# Ruby on Rails- gem devise, ArgumentError:wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I install devise gem and wanted to add some columns on registration page.

app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]


protected

def configure_sign_up_params
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up){|u| u.permit(:company_id, :name, :email, :profile, :prefecture_id, :address, :password, :password_confirmation)}
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.label :campany_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :campany_id, Campany.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.input :name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
<%= f.inneput :email, paceholder:"メールアドレス", required: true, autofocus: true %>
<%= f.input :profile, required: true, autofocus: true %>
*<%= f.label :prefecture_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :prefecture_id, JpPrefecture::Prefecture.all, :code, :name %>
<%= f.input :address, required: true, autofocus: true %>
<%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit, "新規登録" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { 
registrations: 'users/registrations' 
}
```

When I filled out the form and submitted. It show " ArgumentError:wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)" this error! 
Is there some wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add error trace?

Comment: Sorry, Do you mean this?
requirebin/rails
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'

<top (required)>bin/rails
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'

Comment: <top (required)>bin/spring
lockfile = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.default_lockfile.read)
  spring = lockfile.specs.detect { |spec| spec.name == "spring" }
  if spring
    Gem.use_paths Gem.dir, Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path
    gem 'spring', spring.version
    require 'spring/binstub'
  end
end

Comment: can you specify on which line this error occuring check your log inside `log` folder in your rails root directory you can find a file with your environment.

Comment: I checked my log and saw this line.

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):
  devise (4.2.1) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:157:in `password_digest'

Is this the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

In new.html.erb, for input email your input spelling should be **f.input**, also you have given **campany_id** but in controller you have used **company_id**.

And in controller:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up){|u| u.permit(:company_id, :name, :email, :profile, :prefecture_id, :address)}
end
```

You only need to permit parameters which have been added by you. You do not need to permit password or confirm_password.
Also all the parameters permitted or which are there in form need to be in your table.

Hope this helps.